# Torque developed by Star Connected rotor

Tags: motor, torque, rotor, star

The current in each phase of a Y-connected rotor winding is 200 amperes. The resistance per leg is 0.003 ohm. Determine the torque developed by the rotor at a slip of 3%.

I don't understand how to approach this. Like I don't know how to complete the whole problem.

Comment: The assumption is you are referring to a motor. What sort of motor? The other assumption is this is a question as part of your schooling, thus you have received tutelage on said motors. The required learning is in your books etc.

Comment: Yes it is. But I don't how to approach this problem. Usually its T=3/2πNs *I2* I2/Z2 *pf. The problem is I can't find what Ns is. No matter which way. Also, I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: If that's the whole question you can't answer it. If there are more details about the specific motor, ... well only you know those, so we can't answer it for you.

Comment: @user_1818839, That is the whole question in the text book